# Changing the main font in the dialogue package

Tags: dialogue

I am using the `dialogue` package for typesetting some conversations in between main text. The main text is set in serif, I want the dialogues to appear in sans and in a smaller size than the main text.

For the smaller size I currently I am enclosing the dialogue environment inside a small environment, but trying the same with sans is not working. But I need both to be set by default. What can be done in this regard?

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dialogue}

\begin{document}

%  {\textsf % this not working, all text should be in sans by default
   \begin{small} % this works, but needs to be set by default for all 
  % text within dialogue
%   \begin{textsf} % neither is this working
   \begin{dialogue}
\speak{AJ}  This is about the oil.
\speak{AA} What oil?
\speak{AJ} The oil that the current produced.
\end{dialogue}
%\end{textsf}
\end{small}   
%}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redefine the `\PreDialogue` macro to include font switches, i.e.

```
\renewcommand\PreDialogue{\sffamily\small}
```

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dialogue}
\renewcommand\PreDialogue{\sffamily\small}
\begin{document}
Text before dialogue.
\begin{dialogue}
\speak{AJ}  This is about the oil.
\speak{AA} What oil?
\speak{AJ} The oil that the current produced.
\end{dialogue}
Text between dialogue.
\begin{dialogue}
\speak{AJ}  This is about the oil.
\speak{AA} What oil?
\speak{AJ} The oil that the current produced.
\end{dialogue}

\end{document}
```